# Degree of a Segre variety (without Hilbert polynomial)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Algebraic Geometry is not my topic of research and I am having troubles in understanding the following:

In Harris book, Algebraic Geometry, a firs course, Example 18.15, there is a proof of the degree of the Segre varieties $\Sigma_{m,n}$. The author intersects $\Sigma_{m,n} \subset \mathbb{P}(V \otimes W)$ with a subspace of codimension $m+n$ defined by simple tensors of the dual space $V^* \otimes W^*$, that is the subspace is the intersection of hyperplanes that are unions of pullbacks of each factor. The intersection contains at most $\binom{n+m}{n}$ points. I read similar proofs elsewhere. But, as far as I know, to prove that a variety of dimension $k$ has degree $d$, one has to prove that the intersection of the variety with a *GENERAL* subspace of codimension $k$ contains at most $d$ points. How is it possible to use such a special linear subspace and then deduce that it is true for a general one?

Answer (score 5):

You forget the last 3 lines of the proof : "As before, we have to check that the intersection of $\Sigma _{m,n}$ with the hyperplanes
$H_i$ is transverse at each point; assuming this, we deduce that the degree of the
Segre variety  is
$\binom{n+m}{n}$". Indeed, for *any* linear subspace $L$ of the right codimension intersecting transversally  a subvariety $X\subset \mathbb{P}^N$, we have $\#\,L\cap X=\deg (X)$.

Of course checking transversality is not completely trivial; this is why the cohomological approach is simpler.

Comment: Yes, of course we need transversality, what it is not clear to me is how to check the intersection with such a special linear subspace is enough to deduce what happens with the intersection with any linear subspace of the right codimension and intersecting transversally $X$.

Comment: As I said, transversality is enough. Look at Bézout theorem 18.3 in Harris' book.

Comment: Sorry,I don't think I explained myself.Suppose we don't know the degree $d$ of $X$ but we know the dimension $k$. What I would do to find $d$ (but I am not algebraic geometer, so I have a very naive approach) to intersect $X$ with a linear space of codimension $k$ intersecting transversally $X$ and to check how many points I get. What I see in many notes, when $X$ is a Segre variety, is the intersection of $X$ with a subspace that has codimension $k$, intersects transversally $X$ but ALSO it is the intersection of hyperplanes union of pullback of hyperplanes of each factor.

Comment: So it is not the generic transversal subspace, but a special one, why are we allowed to do that?

Comment: Once again (probably for the last time): **any** linear subspace of the right codimension intersecting transversally gives the right number. See Harris, thm. 18.3. The fact that your subspace is special does **not** matter.

Comment: ok, sorry, I think now I see your point!!